# Access denied on NFS over OpenVPN

Tags: networking, docker, nfs, vpn

I'm trying to access a NFS share. The NFS share is in a server I have at home, and I'm trying to access to it from outside my local network.

In order to achieve this, I have started an OpenVPN server on my local network. This works fine and I can connect to the VPN from outside the local network and I can even ping the server and access some other services that are local only. My OpenVPN IP address is 172.27.232.5.

The problem is that I can't mount my NFS share. 
When I connect to the VPN, I can see the shares using showmount command

```
showmount -e 192.168.73.2
Export list for 192.168.73.2:
/media/share/kdab     192.168.73.0/24
/media/share/jjcasmar 192.168.73.0/24
```

but if I try to connect to any of them, it fails.

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 192.168.73.2:/media/share/jjcasmar /home/jjcasmar/mnt
mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.73.2:/media/share/jjcasmar
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my setup, and Im not very good and networks. Any ideas of what might be happening?

The result of `ip addr show` for the VPN connection is

```
13: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 172.27.232.5/23 brd 172.27.233.255 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6` fe80::b6a9:fff6:dd69:6f7f/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If I understand correctly, the NFS server denies the connection because althought I can see the server on 192.168.73.2, I'm not on that subnet, right?

I have tried to modify the exports to add `172.27.232.0/23`, but it's still failing. I have also tried to export directly to my OpenVPN IP, `172.27.232.5` without success.

Comment: welcome to U&L, can you add to your post result of `ip a s` when VPN is connected ?

Answer (score 2):

OpenVPN typically uses a routed network to connect clients to the server. So for example, although your LAN is 192.168.73.0/24 your connected client might be assigned the VPN address 10.0.0.2. Routing allows your client to reach devices on your LAN.

Running `ip addr` (`ip a`) on your client while the VPN is connected will show the subnet being used for OpenVPN - or you can look in the OpenVPN server configuration file (typically under `/etc/openvpn` on the server).

Looking at `showmount` you can see that the NFS exports are being offered only to hosts on your LAN, 192.168.73.0/24.

Your client isn't on 192.168.73.0/24 so it is denied permission. The solution is to modify `/etc/exports` on your server to include access to the OpenVPN subnet.

With NFS v3 I'd do something like this, but I don't know how much is still required for NFS v4:

```
/media/share/kdab     192.168.73.0/24 172.27.232.0/23
/media/share/jjcasmar 192.168.73.0/24 172.27.232.0/23
```

Again, for NFS v3 I'd then run `exportfs -var` but I don't know if that's still required (I've never got on with NFS v4 - too much complexity for no obvious gain).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I thought about something like that, and I also tried to export to the openvpn subnet. The vpn ip is 172.27.232.5, and I tried to export to 172.27.232.0/24, but also failed

Comment: @jjcasmar your VPN is 23 bit not 24, try to add `172.27.232.0/23`

Comment: @Archemar thanks. Example fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Ill try this when Im back home, as I cant ssh the server from outside. I dont understand why is 23 instead of 24. Where can I read about it?

Comment: `man openvpn` on your client or server, and then look at the configuration typically under `/etc/openvpn`.

Comment: I have tried the IP you suggested, but it still failing, dont know why.

Comment: What does the _server_ report in the error logs when you try to mount from the client? (Files are under `/var/log` but without knowing the server OS or Linux distribution I can't attempt to give a specific file to examine.)

Comment: Im using docker, linuxserver/openvpn-as image. Let me find the log and Ill attach to the question

Comment: Ups, sorry. You meant the NFS server. That is ubuntu, without docker.

Comment: Im thinking about this and could it be that the OpenVPN, which is running in docker, is not reaching the NFS, which is running outside docker?